# How to call Cloud Run from out side of Cloud Run/GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-run, google-iap

I have a simple Spring Boot service 'say-hi' to take GET request under /say-hi and return 'hello'. It's deployed in managed Cloud Run. Suppose I don't want to open it to the general public. Now I wanted to do two things:
1. allow developer (I myself) to access 'say-hi' 
2. allow another Spring Boot service outside of Cloud Run be able to make the call to 'say-hi'

**For my goal 1:**

Weird thing is that curl command doesn't work, but Insomnia works fine. Basically, I followed [the doc](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/developers), I added my google account to roles/run.invoker, but the curl command says Network is unrechable:
 `curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-identity-token)" http://say-hi-0-1-0-q6g2cgbzna-ew.a.run.app:8080/say-hi -v`
Errors:

```
*   Trying 216.239.36.53...
*   Trying 2001:4860:4802:36::35...
* Immediate connect fail for 2001:4860:4802:36::35: Network is unreachable
*   Trying 2001:4860:4802:36::35...
* Immediate connect fail for 2001:4860:4802:36::35: Network is unreachable
*   Trying 2001:4860:4802:36::35...
* Immediate connect fail for 2001:4860:4802:36::35: Network is unreachable
```

However, if I run `gcloud auth print-identity-token` separately to get the token first and then sent the GET request from Insomnia client, it works...  I'm wondering why...

**For my goal 2**
I assume the right session to look at it [here](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/service-to-service#calling_from_outside_gcp). Does this mean if I wanted to access 'say-hi' from outside of Cloud Run manged (both from my own laptop and from other GKE instances), I need to have IAP enable for my project? if yes, how to integrate cloud run with IAP?

Answer (score 3):

After a long day of searching and reading. Finally get a working version. The given doc of [service-to-service authentication](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/service-to-service#calling_from_outside_gcp) given by Google Cloud Run was really misleading me towards IAP, and [the code here](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/authentication-howto#authenticating_from_a_service_account) left a few places unclarified. Turned out to call Cloud Run service, I didn't need IAP at all. Big thanks to [this blog](https://medium.com/google-cloud/authenticating-using-google-openid-connect-tokens-e7675051213b) where I grabbed the solution from.

```
  @PostMapping(value="/call-say-hi")
  public ResponseEntity<String> callSayHi() throws URISyntaxException, IOException {

    ServiceAccountCredentials serviceAccountCredentials =
        ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_JSON_KEY_PATH));
    serviceAccountCredentials.createScoped(IAM_SCOPE);
    IdTokenCredentials idTokenCredentials = IdTokenCredentials.newBuilder()
                                            .setIdTokenProvider(serviceAccountCredentials)
                                            .setTargetAudience(TARGET_AUDIENCE)
                                            .build();
    GenericUrl genericUrl = new GenericUrl(TARGET_AUDIENCE+"/say-hi");
    HttpCredentialsAdapter adapter = new HttpCredentialsAdapter(idTokenCredentials);
    HttpRequest request = httpTransport.createRequestFactory(adapter).buildGetRequest(genericUrl);
    request.setThrowExceptionOnExecuteError(false);
    HttpResponse response = request.execute();
    String r = response.parseAsString();
    System.out.println(r);
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(r);
  }
```

Where the TARGET_AUDIENCE is the deployed Cloud Run service URL

Comment: The #createScoped call seems superfluous.

Also, for comparison, I'm using GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=service_account_creds.json and  "(IdTokenProvider) GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault()" instead of loading them myself. This then also automatically works in cloud run->cloud run.

Comment: @mernst the scope is a separate thing than the credential I believe.  the scope doesn't give you any permission is the service account credential is missing.  But your way of getting the service account is definitely preferred.

Comment: Your code snippet doesn't use the result of createScoped so I doubt that has any effect.

Comment: It saved my lots of time. Really helpful.